# Guava java EventBus instantiation error

Tags: java, exception, publish, guava, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to use EventBus of Google's Guava libraries.

From Guava's [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/index.html) it should be easy to instantiate an EventBus object.

My code:

```
package test;

import com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventBus bus = new EventBus("Sample");
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Objects.firstNonNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.getKeyStrength(CacheBuilder.java:355)
at com.google.common.cache.CustomConcurrentHashMap.<init>(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:206)
at com.google.common.cache.ComputingCache.<init>(ComputingCache.java:39)
at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.build(CacheBuilder.java:569)
at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.<init>(EventBus.java:156)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:7)
Java Result: 1
```

I've tried with Guava 10.0, 11.0 and 12.0 and always the same error. I'm on OSX Lion and I'm using Netbeans 7.1: I've tried both Java 6 (32 and 64bit) and Java 7: no improvements. On google i can't find anything. Is it a problem with Guava? Or, as usually, am I missing something?

Best regards,

Alessandro

Comment: At first glance this looks like an error you usually get when you have different versions of the same jar file on your classpath.

Comment: I've just tried on Windows with same settings and it works fine. I'll try to see if I've got different versions of the same jar. I'll let you know

Comment: Try the `-verbose:class` command line option to see where your classes are actually loaded from.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. I had some jars in /System/Library/Java/Extensions that had implemented a different version of Guava: -verbose:class was a good suggest :)

Answer (score 17):

To expand on what @biziclop said, you most likely have both a recent version of Guava and either google-collect or a version of Guava prior to 3.0 on your classpath. Objects.firstNonNull was added in 3.0, suggesting that an old version of that class is being loaded.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning google-collections in this answer - that was my problem.  Excluding it in the pom does the trick.

Comment: I had 2 versions of guava and it was giving me Objects.firstNonNull  error: cannot find symbol. Removing one of them fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was using google-collections 1.0 where guava is v11. This problem went away after I upgraded to

`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>`

from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```